# lxml etree parse function core dump

Tags: python, lxml

I am using lxml etree 2 ways to parse a file. The first way works, the second core dumps. But the second way seems to be allowed by the doc. Any idea?

First way - no problem:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> etree.parse(open("test.src"))
<lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0xd41a70>
```

Second way - core dump:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> etree.parse("test.src")
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Test.src xml file (from w3c site):

```
"<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>"
```

I'm in python 2.6.6 on linux 2.6.32-131.4.1.el6.x86_64 and my version of lxml is 2.3.4.

Comment: Can you try to narrow this down to a simpler XML file that you can publish here? Or a publicly available one?

Comment: Let me try that - good idea.

Comment: Done - seems to still crash with the very simple xml file I added in the post.

Comment: Seems like an old version of lxml - could you install v3.3.1 using pip in a virtualenv and test again?

Comment: I don't get this on Python 2.7.5, lxml 2.3.4 (in a virtualenv), libxml2 2.9.1, libxslt1.1.28 on a 64 bit machine (Ubuntu 13.10 3.11.0-17-generic). It might actually be one of those underlying libraries.

Comment: @Peter - unfortunately, I don't control the libs/versions I have to use on my box. I wish I could. I can try to re-install libxml2 and libxslt. I'll try this tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Frank In that case, I would say it's just an old bug that has since been fixed. Can you cope with just using the `open('test.src')` method in your application?

Comment: Yeah - that will probably have to be the workaround. Thanks!

Comment: @Frank Just for added clarity, lxml versions lower than `2.3.5` have this bug that causes segmentation faults: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/984936